# If a row is not unique - ignore it - php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, select, fetch

I'm working on the following code:

```
function form_Subcat_Picker() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }       
    $catPicker = "SELECT Subcatid, Subcatname, Parentid
            FROM ProductSubCats
            ORDER BY Subcatid";
    if ($Result = $mysqli->query($catPicker)){
        if (!$Result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            echo '<div class="parentid'.$row['Parentid'].'">';
            echo '<select name="Subcatid">';
            echo '<option value="'.$row["Subcatid"].'">'.$row["Subcatname"]."</option>";
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

What I want to do, is in the line:

```
while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            echo '<div class="parentid'.$row['Parentid'].'">';
```

If the $row['Parentid'] part is the same as the previous iteration, I want to ignore that particular line (adding the div class)

So that if for example in the first run $row['Parentid'] is 1, and in the next loop it is 1 again, I want to not create a new div, just echo everything else and thus keep it in the same div.

Is this possible? Alternatively, how could I make multiple sub category id's and names appear in the one div, if they share a common parentid (there are multiple parent ids)
For the line:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row["Subcatid"].'">'.$row["Subcatname"]."</option>";
```

Comment: `mysql_error()` in mysqli code - take a little care. It's not answering your question, just what jumped into the eye. also do not query two times the same query. Just not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work:

```
$last_id = 0;
while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($last_id != $row['Parentid']) {
        echo '<div class="parentid'.$row['Parentid'].'">';
        echo '<select name="Subcatid">';
        echo '<option value="'.$row["Subcatid"].'">'.$row["Subcatname"]."</option>";
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</div>';
        $last_id = $row['Parentid'];
    }
}
```

However, I think the best solution is to filter them out in the SQL statement, maybe the `GROUP BY` clause, but I'm not 100% sure how to do it :).

Regards,

Comment: Went with a combination of all three in the end, this worked well :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

That is just something basic for looping. Let's see your current loop:

```
 while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     ...
 }
```

As you want to skip with a specific condition, let's just introduce this skipping (not taking much care about the condition first):

```
 while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     if ($condition) continue;
     ...
 }
```

Now let's formulate the condition. As we want to look into the last `$row` we need to keep a copy:

```
 $last = null;
 while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     if ($condition) continue;
     ...
     $last = $row;
 }
```

Now we've got the data we need to have to create the condition, `$last` can contain the last row (if there was one) and therefore the comparison can be done:

```
 $last = null;
 while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     $condition = $last && $row['Parentid'] === $last['Parentid'];
     if ($condition) continue;
     ...
     $last = $row;
 }
```

And that is it basically. Depending on the logic, you might want to switch to a `for` loop:

```
 for ($last = null; $row = $Result->fetch_assoc(); $last = $row) { 
     $condition = $last && $row['Parentid'] === $last['Parentid'];
     if ($condition) continue;
     ...         
 }
```

This for example does ensure that for each iteration (even the skipped ones), the `$last` is set to the `$row` at the end of the loop.

Instead of `continue` you can naturally do different things, like not outputting the `<div>` or similar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'd write it.

```
// add a variable to hold the previous value
$previous_parent_id = "";

while ($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) { 

  // then add an if statement to see if it's the previous statement
  if ($row['parent_id'] != $previous_parent_id){
    echo '<div class="parent_id'.$row['parent_id'].'">';
    $previous_parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
  }
}
```

So going in a loop on these records

```
ID ParentID
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  1
4  2
4  2
```

the output would be:

```
<div class="parent_id0">
<div class="parent_id1">
<div class="parent_id2">
```